# Customizing locals based on Devise scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, locals

I have a User and a Client model setup to use Devise with different sign-up workflows. I want to customize the locals based on the resource (Client or User). For example, instead of using the default devise message in `config/locals/devise.en.yml` for unconfirmed accounts

```
unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
```

I want two separate messages for Client and Users.

Is there a way to do this by setting up two different locales? e.g., something like,

```
devise.user.en.yml
```

and

```
devise.client.en.yml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in one file like this:

```
 en:
      devise:
        sessions:
          user:
            signed_in: 'Welcome user, you are signed in.'
          admin:
            signed_in: 'Hello admin!'
```

Where user and admin are the resources. Clients and users in your case.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise